# Can I turn off the HttpSession in web.xml?

Tags: java, session, web-applications, web.xml

I would like to eliminate the HttpSession completely - can I do this in web.xml? I'm sure there are container specific ways to do it (which is what crowds the search results when I do a Google search).

P.S. Is this a bad idea? I prefer to completely disable things until I actually need them.

Comment: What an interesting question. I have a situation where with Tomcat, no session is being created for me, so I was searching for whether there was a way to turn the session _on_ in web.xml. :D

Answer (score 82, accepted):

> *I would like to eliminate the HttpSession completely*

You can't entirely disable it. All you need to do is to just **not** to get a handle of it by either `request.getSession()` or `request.getSession(true)` anywhere in your webapplication's code and making sure that your JSPs don't implicitly do that by setting `<%@page session="false"%>`.

If your main concern is actually disabling the cookie which is been used behind the scenes of `HttpSession`, then you can in Java EE 5 / Servlet 2.5 only do so in the server-specific webapp configuration. In for example Tomcat you can set the `cookies` attribute to `false` in `<Context>` element.

```
<Context cookies="false">
```

Also see this [Tomcat specific documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html). This way the session won't be retained in the subsequent requests which aren't URL-rewritten --only whenever you grab it from the request for some reason. After all, if you don't need it, **just** don't grab it, then it won't be created/retained at all.

Or, if you're already on Java EE 6 / Servlet 3.0 or newer, and really want to do it via `web.xml`, then you can use the new `<cookie-config>` element in `web.xml` as follows to zero-out the max age:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <max-age>0</max-age>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

If you want to hardcode in your webapplication so that `getSession()` never returns a `HttpSession` (or an "empty" `HttpSession`), then you'll need to create a filter listening on an `url-pattern` of `/*` which replaces the `HttpServletRequest` with a [`HttpServletRequestWrapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html) implementation which returns on all `getSession()` methods `null`, or a dummy custom `HttpSession` implementation which does nothing, or even throws `UnsupportedOperationException`.

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    chain.doFilter(new HttpServletRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request) {
        @Override
        public HttpSession getSession() {
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public HttpSession getSession(boolean create) {
            return null;
        }
    }, response);
}
```

---

> *P.S. Is this a bad idea? I prefer to completely disable things until I actually need them.*

If you don't need them, just don't use them. That's all. Really :)

Comment: The `HttpServletRequestWrapper` sounds good, I would go with that. In a large project with many developers you need some enforcement of architectural decisions (like statelessness). You can't rely on people "simply not using it".

Comment: _"If you don't need them, just don't use them"_ It is not that simple. Some of the hundreds of libraries your project uses might create a session somewhere.

Comment: @David: then just question the library in question?

Comment: @Balus so there is no application server that can handle requests without creating the HttpSession and storing the data for at least one minute? Right?

Comment: It is so sad to see that Java EE was simply NOT designed for stateless, sessionless applications, which is one of the best modern technique to build scalable web applications. That is also the reason of emerging new technologies such as express.js and Play framework. They are stateless by default and they are indeed very scalable server side frameworks that can easily serve thousands concurrently on a single regular machine. I recommend using them for new projects.

Comment: @bekce: Uh, whilst Java EE is indeed not stateless by default, you can make it (at least JSP, Servlets and JSF) stateless as answered above (simply don't touch `HttpSession` in first place). So I don't see why this would be a reason to migrate to an entirely different web framework. Moreover, scalability doesn't depend on statelessness at all. Look at Google as an example, it definitely isn't stateless :)

Comment: @BalusC  
Even if you don't touch that object, the server will definitely create one for you in the memory, which is terrible for GC and from security perspective if you have lots of them. The problem of Java EE is that it was designed to solve everything even load balancing, session replication, clustering, messaging all in suboptimal ways compared to current technology and it lost its competence along the way. Modern systems should use Redis or Hazelcast for session replication which scale well.

Comment: @becke: "definitely"? Apparently you've only worked with buggy servers. This is namely nowhere defined in servlet spec. Even then, your GC and security concerns are ungrounded. Sorry, your subjective comments so far sound too much like fanboy speeches from a disgruntled user. Stack Overflow is not the right place for that. Try Reddit instead.

Comment: @BalusC Regarding JSP-s: in case we use the approach you suggested to override the getSession() methods, do we still need to explicitly add <%@page session="false"%> tags to JSP-s? Or do the automated session creation in the JSP lifecycle also fall back to the same getSession() methods?

Comment: In my application, the jsp pages seem to implicitly create a session. I tried to use <%@page session="false"%> but then the page could not be loaded anymore. I also tried to disable cookies in the context.xml but it didn´t work either.

Comment: @FranzDeschler: just put a breakpoint in session creation and inspect call stack to nail down who's doing that and why.

Comment: @BalusC thanks. It works now. I had to add it to all jsp files. Not only the root-jsp but all included ones too.

Answer (score 10):

If you are building a stateless high load application you can disable using cookies for session tracking like this (non-intrusive, probably container-agnostic):

```
<session-config>
    <tracking-mode>URL</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

To enforce this architectural decision write something like this:

```
public class PreventSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
@Override
public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Session use is forbidden");
}

@Override
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Session use is forbidden");
}
}
```

And add it to web.xml and fix places where it fails with that exception:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.ideas.bucketlist.web.PreventSessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 7):

In Spring Security 3 with Java Config, you can use HttpSecurity.sessionManagement():

```
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}
```

Xml looks like this;

```
<http create-session="stateless">
  <!-- config -->
</http>
```

By the way, the difference between NEVER and STATELESS

> NEVER:Spring Security will never create an HttpSession, but will use
>   the HttpSession if it already exists
>
> STATELESS:Spring Security will never create an HttpSession and it will
>   never use it to obtain the SecurityContext

Comment: @ArtemNovikov What's your Spring Security version? This future is supported since 3.1

Comment: This means that Spring Security will never create an HttpSession but leaves open the door for other parts of code that can request the session creation by using getSession() as stated in BalusC answer

Answer (score 4):

I use the following method for my RESTful app to remove any inadvertent session cookies from being created *and* used.

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <max-age>0</max-age>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

However, this does not turn off HttpSessions altogether.  A session may still be created by the application inadvertently, even if it disappears in a minute and a rogue client may ignore the max-age request for the cookie as well.

The advantage of this approach is you don't need to change your application, just `web.xml`.  I would recommend you create an `HttpSessionListener` that will log when a session is created or destroyed so you can track when it occurs.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to eliminate the HttpSession completely - can I do this in web.xml? I'm sure there are container specific ways to do it

I don't think so. Disabling the `HttpSession` would be a violation of the Servlet spec which states that `HttpServletRequest#getSession` should return a session or create one. So I wouldn't expect a Java EE container to provide such a configuration option (that would make it non compliant).

> Is this a bad idea? I prefer to completely disable things until I actually need them.

Well, I don't really get the point, just don't put anything in the session if you don't want to use it. Now, if you really want to prevent the use of the session, you can use a `Filter` to replace the request with a implementation of `HttpServletRequestWrapper` overriding `getSession()`. But I wouldn't waste time implementing this :)

**Update:** My initial suggestion was not optimal, the "right" (*cough*) way would be to replace the request.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than disabling you can rewrite the URL using a URL rewrite filter eg [tuckey rewrite filter](https://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/). This will give Google friendly results but still allow cookie based session handling.

However, you should probably disable it for all responses as it's worse than just search engine unfriendly. It exposes the session ID which can be used for [certain security exploits](https://randomcoder.org/articles/jsessionid-considered-harmful).

[Example config](https://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/manual/4.0/guide.html) for Tuckey filter:

```
<outbound-rule encodefirst="true">
  <name>Strip URL Session ID's</name>
  <from>^(.*?)(?:\;jsessionid=[^\?#]*)?(\?[^#]*)?(#.*)?$</from>
  <to>$1$2$3</to>
</outbound-rule>
```

Answer (score 2):

As of Servlet 3.0, you can make it so sessions are not tracked by the servlet container in any way, by adding code like this to the `contextInitialized` method of a `ServletContextListener`:

```
servletContext.setSessionTrackingModes(Collections.emptySet());
```

[Javadoc.](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#setSessionTrackingModes(java.util.Set))

Comment: Thank you. Worked fine with jetty. I needed a way to avoid session creation without having to ensure each .jsp had <%@ page session="false" %> configured and so far it is the best solution to meet my needs.

Answer (score 1):

For RESTful application, I simply invalidate it every time the request's lifecycle ends. There may be some web server that always creates new session when new client access whether you call `request.getSession()` or not.

Answer (score 1):

One cannot avoid the session creation. But you can check if you violate your own requirement at the end of a request cycle. So, create a simple servlet filter, which you place as first and after chain.doFilter throw an exception if a session was created:

```
chain.doFilter(request, response);
if(request.getSession(false) != null)
    throw new RuntimeException("Somewhere request.getSession() was called");
```