# Java servlet - Session cleanup (HttpServletRequest)

Tags: java, session, servlets, request

General question about java servlets and the best way to handle requests. If I hit my doGet method from a remote server request:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
  ....
  <do work here>
  ....
  kill(request);
}

private void kill(HttpServletRequest request) {
//How do I kill the user session here?
}
```

After I process the request at my end and generate my output to the requester, I want to basically "kill" their session. Currently, that session lingers and thus eats up memory. Then once the max is reached, all other calls are timed out.

I tried creating a HttpSession object using the request object, but got the same results:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.invalidate();
```

Comment: I have the impression that your concrete problem needs to be solved in a different way.

Comment: Probably. The ultimate goal is I want to end a session in my session pool after their request is handled. Whether or not that is killing the request object or creating a session object for that session to delete it, I am not sure.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if (session != null) {
    session.invalidate();
}
```

is the proper way to go as suggested by the documentation. A new session will be created once the client sends a new request.

You mentioned that your sessions still take up memory. Do you have any other references to those objects on the session?

You also might want to have a look at: [Servlet Session behavior and Session.invalidate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879986/servlet-session-behavior-and-session-invalidate)

Answer (score 5):

you can remove an attribute from a session using

```
session.removeAttribute("attribute name");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
session = request.getSession(false); // so if no session is active no session is created
if (session != null)
  session.setMaxInactiveInterval(1); // so it expires immediatly
```

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want Session behavior i.e, having state between multiple requests. Why do you want to create/use session at all. Do not create session or do not store anything in the session.

To make sure that your code is not using session, write a request wrapper which will override `getSession()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Set a time-out period in web.xml