# How do you disable session creation for all JSPs with Tiles?

Tags: java, jsp, session, tomcat, tiles

Is there any way to make all my JSPs not create sessions when using Jasper (Tomcat)?
Apparently Jasper will create a session unless you specify not to:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" session="false" %>
```

Is there way to do this for the entire webapp (session="false")?

Its seems you can't change:

```
org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.getPageContext
```

Which will create a session unless the JSP says session=false.

Comment: I have the same situation here. Now im resorting to eclipse template for jsp that automatically includes the page directive with session="false".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is container-specific; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255814/can-i-turn-off-the-httpsession-in-web-xml).

Comment: I gave up on this one. Ended up just writing a groovy script that checks for session="false" in my JSPX files.