# how to calculate online user count from HttpSessionEventPublisher

Tags: spring, session, listener

i want to calculate user online or active sessions by `HttpSessionEventPublisher` my web.xml file as bellow  :

```
 <listener>
        <listener-class>my.web.application.SessionManager</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

and my class `SessionManager` is:

```
import org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
public class SessionManager extends HttpSessionEventPublisher {

    private static int userCount;
    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        userCount++;
        super.sessionCreated(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        userCount--;
        super.sessionDestroyed(event);
    }

    public static int getUserCount() {
        return userCount;
    }
}
```

when start application `4` session creating , but should be `1` create session, how to solve my problem?
thanks

Comment: And why should it be 1 session and not 4? You can do concurrent requests and if you use JSP you will always get a session (even if it is a temporary one). You can counter act this by adding `session="false"` to your JSP see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093032/how-do-you-disable-session-creation-for-all-jsps-with-tiles

Comment: i want to calculate online user count , how do it  ? with problem, Thanks

Comment: You are using Spring Security then use Spring Security. Judging by the fact that you are extending the `HttpSessionEventPublisher` I also assume you have something for concurrent sessions or session management in place and hence a `SessionRegistry` use that.