# Disable session on embedded http server

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Can these properties used to disable the session mechanism completely?

```
server.session.persistent=false
server.session.timeout=0
```

If not, how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "disable session[s]"? What sort of behaviour change are you expecting comparing to the default "out-of-the-box" Spring Boot app?

Comment: no those parameters will not disable sessions. closest answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255814/can-i-turn-off-the-httpsession-in-web-xml which says we can not disable sessions in tomcat.

Answer (score 2):

had success with setting it to an empty set: `server.servlet.session.tracking-modes=`

@see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#server-properties

@see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/2.2.0.RELEASE/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/server/Session.html#setTrackingModes-java.util.Set-

Comment: Nice trick. After setting this empty, the JSESSIONID had gone...

Answer (score 1):

try type in application.properties:

```
spring.session.store-type=none
```

...to disable spring session

See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-session

Answer (score -1):

A couple of notes for posterity:

1. Persistent sessions are sessions that survive server restarts, thus, when you enable that, Spring will serialize and store your session somewhere to load it later.
2. For a complete discussion on how to reliably disable sessions, please see this post: [Can I turn off the HttpSession in web.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255814/can-i-turn-off-the-httpsession-in-web-xml)