# How to prevent sessions in a tomcat for servlets with basic-auth?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, tomcat8

I'm using `spring-boot-starter-web` to create a `war` app that is deployed on a standalone `tomcat8`.

I have `@EnableWebSecurity` to force `basic-authentication` on each servlet request, and also to secure the gui.

But the main purpose is providing a webservice XML, that is mainly accessed programmatically. Thus, the clients send their `GET` requests always with *basic-auth*.

Problem: tomcat will create a new session for each request! And as the clients connect programmatically to the xml servlets, the sessions are never *logged-out*. And also not reused as the next client request will again transmit the basic-auth.

So those sessions reside in the tomcat until timeout (eg default 30mins). And consume memory meanwhile.

Question: how can I tell tomcat or the spring-servlets that connections providing the basic-auth *http header* don't need to create a session? Just authenticate the user, send the response and forget about session infomration?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255814/can-i-turn-off-the-httpsession-in-web-xml

Comment: If you mean the use of `SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS`: how can I apply this to specific path only, and leave eg the `/gui` path stateful?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the session creation policy to [`SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/http/SessionCreationPolicy.html#STATELESS)

> Spring Security will never create an HttpSession and it will never use it to obtain the SecurityContext

Set it in your `WebSecurityConfiguration` such as:

```
http.antMatcher("/api/**")
              .sessionManagement()
              .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
```

Answer (score 0):

`SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER` is the correct answer here. Because it won't create a session by default. But if a session is requested (eg due to a form login in my /gui path), it will be used.

This way, none of the programmatic requests create a session. But if tested inside a webbrowser (and thus secured by a form login to provide basic-auth), the session is created. Which is the desired behavior because nobody wants to enter the basic-auth credentials each time when sending a request from within a browser.

`http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER);`

Comment: Nice that you find a session creation policy working for all your cases but you can also apply different policies on different set of endpoints with something such as `http.antMatcher("/api/**").sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(.....)`.