# How to avoid jsession id being appended to url?

Tags: java, jsp, jsf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to disable jsessionid in tomcat servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962729/is-it-possible-to-disable-jsessionid-in-tomcat-servlet)

We have a  Spring , JSF application at [Skill-Guru](http://www.skill-guru.com)

Problem:

User opens the site by visiting through a url or directly typing www.skill-guru.com in url.
Now when the user clicks on any link first time, a jsession id is appended to the url. for eg
http://www.skill-guru.com/test/62/pmp-certification-practice-test;jsessionid=3FBFDD1C6C8A9A2FC4FE7C282A60DE4D

After that clicking on any link or url, this session id will not be appended.
But this id is appended in google webmaster links, users who copy the link , copy with jession id.

I do not want the jsession id appended to the url.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What application server are you using?

Comment: Of course you don't.  Just do a Google search on jsessionid and you'll see all these braindeadly badly designed websites polluting Google's cache (and harming their own SEO ranking for what Google considers duplicate content and hence, rightfully, penalize them).  All you need to know is here: http://randomcoder.com/articles/jsessionid-considered-harmful    Disable that jsessionid crap, it's another Java monstrosity ;)

Comment: @Nooz: Don't be harsh about Java ;) PHP and ASP also have such construct (PHPSESSID, ASPSESSIONID). It's really the only way to track the client session on a fresh new session (when the client hasn't sent the session cookie back so that the server can confirm that it supports cookies). You only see this less often in PHP and ASP because you have to include it manually.

Comment: Btw: the HTML source of this site is malformed. You've multiple `<html>`, `<body>`, `<head>` and `<meta>` elements at places where they don't belong. Check the way how you're including template files.

Comment: We are using Tomcat 6.0. 
@BalusC thanks for your input. Will look into these issues.

Comment: @Nooz Please do not be harsh about java. It has so much other goodnes.