# How to disable struts jsessionid in the URL

Tags: java, ajax, servlets, struts

i need to disable or remove the Jsessionid in the URL how to do that, whether it causes any side effect during ajax request.I am using struts 1.2 version.

Answer (score 2):

Servlet 3.0 allows you to specify the means of maintaining a session.

I guess you are not using it, so see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962729/is-it-possible-to-disable-jsessionid-in-tomcat-servlet). I favour the 2nd answer more than the rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `JSESSIONID` from your ajax call, your servlet container won't identify your application and the resources stored in the session, (which is a side-effect, depending on your requirement).

E.g. retrieving a list of protected resources (that requires authorization). If the user had logged in (and user info is logged in a session), and Ajax doesn't pass the `JSESSIONID`, there's no way to verify user who logged in (as there is no application session). So, no protected resources is retrieved.

Just a 2cent thought.

Comment: If cookies are enabled, the browser will identify the jsessionid via the cookie value.

Comment: @Steven Benites, and on ajax calls?

Comment: @Elite: Cookies are still sent with Ajax requests.