# Generate a new session Id

Tags: servlets, session-fixation

How to generate new session id with out extends HttpServlet class. Is it mandatory to extend HttpServlet class & Is it mandatory to genarate new session id with in doGet method

```
public class LoginSupport extends ActionSupport {

    public void prepare() {
        HttpSession session = ServletActionContext.getRequest().getSession();
        session.invalidate();
        //How to genarate new session id
    }
}
```

Comment: Another call to `HttpServletRequest#getSession()` should re-create the session and generate a new ID

Answer (score 3):

After calling `HttpSession#invalidate()`, you can create a new session by calling `HttpServletRequest#getSession()`.

For example

```
public void prepare() {
    final HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
    request.getSession().invalidate();

    // generate new session (and id)
    final HttpSession newSession = request.getSession();
}
```

The next HTTP response from your server should include a new session ID, eg

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=6a303082951311647336934;path=/
```

---

From https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession--

> **getSession**
>
> `HttpSession getSession()`
>
> Returns the current session associated with this request, or if the request does not have a session, **creates one**.

Comment: It is not working, could you tell me what should i put within prepare method?

Comment: Literally what I have in my answer.

Comment: I put your code after my code with in prepare method, but It is not working  & why do we destroy one session Id twice??

Comment: When I using this method, Value of destroyed session ID is equals to new session ID and I got these errors "ERROR - Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception" and "java.lang.IllegalStateException: getAttribute: Session already invalidated"

Comment: What HTTP container are you using? Jersey, Tomcat, something else? What version?

Comment: @Mapa that error means you're trying to so something with an an already invalidated session

Comment: I'm using jboss

Comment: Might be related to this question of mine from a very long time ago ~ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824724/session-id-re-used-after-call-to-invalidate. In my research on that, I'd found that JBoss exhibits this behaviour

Comment: Yes.. within my jboss server.xml file emptySessionPath="true" should it be false

Comment: @Mapa perhaps open another question for that one. I've never used JBoss

Answer (score 3):

When on Servlet 3.1 or newer (Java EE 7), just use [`HttpServletRequest#changeSessionId()`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#changeSessionId--).

```
request.changeSessionId();
```

It won't invalidate the session but just change the value of the `JSESSIONID` cookie.