# How to keep URL same for all request

Tags: java, struts

I am working on a website, where I am using Java/Java EE/struts.

When I request any page it shows me session id and all other stuff in URL. Will some one please help me how to get rid of. I am reading about URL rewriting. But  I am not getting how to implement it.
Ex.

**http://mywebsite.com/welcome.do;jsessionid=6E79E050360BAC1858CA7AC7974D75C7**

I want it to be **http://mywebsite.com/** only.

This is useful for SEO also.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to disable jsessionid in tomcat servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962729/is-it-possible-to-disable-jsessionid-in-tomcat-servlet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you set the canonical URL instead if you are worried about SEO.

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html

Answer (score 0):

Stripping the session id is useful for security and might be for SEO. Keeping the URL identical for all requests isn't.

You want a search engine to distinguish between the different pages of your site. Also you want people/sites to be able to link to a specific page on your website.