# Remove jsessionid in URL Struts 2

Tags: struts2

I have developed a web application with session management in Struts2. Every time user logins, jsessionid appeared in the URL. How to remove disable jessionid in appending in URL? I am using Struts 2.0.11.

Answer (score 1):

You could disable url rewriting on your container level (and in fact it works for every framework leveraging the HttpServletResponse#encodeURL method).. In servlet 2.5 url rewriting is optional and on most servlet containers there should be a way to disable this. For instance in Tomcat you can set disableURLRewriting attribute to true. More [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html). Also check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962729/is-it-possible-to-disable-jsessionid-in-tomcat-servlet) - it seems to be similar.