# Tomcat appends jsessionid in the URL not working

Tags: url, tomcat, struts

When i log in using my website URL, jsessionid is appended with my URL and its gives HTTP Status 404 error.

```
http://site.domain/Login;jsessionid=3C0374FECFDE19DD7C4E89F80965E201
```

How to remove it from URL? FYI: I am using struts1.2 and Tomcat5.5.

Thanks in advance

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962729/is-it-possible-to-disable-jsessionid-in-tomcat-servlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented it using below URL concept. Thanks for your suggestions.
http://randomcoder.org/articles/jsessionid-considered-harmful