# Tomcat j_security error with CAS and LDAP

Tags: tomcat, cas

we are having some issues with out tomcats and j_security. Without any changes, after restarting then, they started to fail with the following error:

*[http-8180-Processor23] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[some.fake.address].[/].[default] - Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.securityfilter.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:120)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:880)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)*

They authenticate users against a CAS server, retrieving data from a LDAP. All other services (moodle, php) using the CAS server are working properly, and a third tomcat server (that we did not restart yet) is also working. Can anyone figure out the problem or how to start debugging it? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This issue may be the same derived from a possible bug since Tomcat 6.0.33, which is explained in this thread: [Is it possible to disable jsessionid in tomcat servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962729/is-it-possible-to-disable-jsessionid-in-tomcat-servlet)