# Why URL rewriting is not working in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, url, struts2, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I have configured Tuckey URL Rewriting.  I have included dependency in `pom.xml`:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.tuckey</groupId>
            <artifactId>urlrewritefilter</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

added filter in `web.xml`:

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>logLevel</param-name>
            <param-value>commons</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>confReloadCheckInterval</param-name>
            <param-value>60</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter> 
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>    
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

created `urlrewriter.xml` under `WEB-INF` folder

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite3.0.dtd">

<urlrewrite default-match-type="wildcard">
    <!-- Struts -->
    <rule match-type="regex">
        <from>^/Profile/([0-9]+)$</from>
        <to>/Profile?id=$1</to>
    </rule>   
 
    <!-- Remove JSESSIONID from URLs when cookies disabled -->
    <!-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962729/is-it-possible-to-disable-jsessionid-in-tomcat-servlet -->
    <outbound-rule encodefirst="true" match-type="regex">
        <name>Strip URL Session ID's</name>
        <from>^(.*?)(?:\;jsessionid=[^\?#]*)?(\?[^#]*)?(#.*)?$</from>
        <to>$1$2$3</to>
    </outbound-rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

Now from browser I am requesting `http://localhost:8080/Test/Profile/123`

This in not redirection to `http://localhost:8080/Test/Profile?id=123`

How to make this working?

**EDIT:**

At debug  I am getting following result at Tomcat log

```
24-Jan-2018 17:06:45.588 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-163] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter DEBUG: starting conf reload check
24-Jan-2018 17:06:45.589 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-163] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter DEBUG: conf is not modified
24-Jan-2018 17:06:45.589 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-163] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ServerNameMatcher DEBUG: looking for hostname match on current server name localhost
24-Jan-2018 17:06:45.589 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-163] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter DEBUG: checking for status path on /test/Profile/2345
24-Jan-2018 17:06:45.589 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-163] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter DEBUG: processing request for /Profile/2345
24-Jan-2018 17:06:45.590 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-163] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleBase DEBUG: Rule 0 run called with /Profile/2345
24-Jan-2018 17:06:45.590 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-163] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleBase DEBUG: matched "from"
24-Jan-2018 17:06:45.590 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-163] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.substitution.MatcherReplacer DEBUG: found 1
24-Jan-2018 17:06:45.590 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-163] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.substitution.MatcherReplacer DEBUG: replaced sb is /Profile?id=2345
24-Jan-2018 17:06:45.590 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-163] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleExecutionOutput DEBUG: needs to be forwarded to /Profile?id=2345
24-Jan-2018 17:06:45.590 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-163] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter DEBUG: rule is last
24-Jan-2018 17:06:45.590 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-163] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter DEBUG: starting conf reload check
24-Jan-2018 17:06:45.590 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-163] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter DEBUG: conf is not modified
24-Jan-2018 17:06:45.591 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-163] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ServerNameMatcher DEBUG: looking for hostname match on current server name localhost
24-Jan-2018 17:06:45.591 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-163] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter DEBUG: checking for status path on /test/Profile
24-Jan-2018 17:06:45.591 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-163] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter DEBUG: processing request for /Profile
24-Jan-2018 17:06:45.591 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-163] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleBase DEBUG: Rule 0 run called with /Profile
```

Tomcat console is showing:

```
 MonitorFilter::WARNING: the monitor filter must be the first filter in the chain.
```

Comment: The log shows that it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite any URL if you place [Tuckey URL rewrite](https://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) filter before the Struts2 filter in the web application deployment descriptor. Use this guide: [Tuckey URLRewrite How-To](https://devtidbits.com/2011/11/28/tuckey-urlrewrite-how-to/).

---

Also you can use URL rewrite mod for Apache Web Server in front of your servlet container.  Use this guide: [URL Rewriting for Beginners](https://www.elated.com/mod-rewrite-tutorial-for-absolute-beginners/).

Comment: tuckey filter is before the struts2 filter I have updted the web.xml in in question

Comment: Read the guide, debug, after that tell us the problem.

Comment: Requesting url is matching and it is replaced with forwarded url but my action class is not get called

Comment: It is because the request is forwarded to wrong URL and action mapper can&#39;t find mapping for that URL. You should read the guide if you want  the filter to forward to the action with the correct regex.

Comment: I am following the document  http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/manual/3.0/guide.html        from there i got this example  `<rule>
        <from>^/products/([0-9]+)$</from>
        <to>/products/index.jsp?product_id=$1</to>
    </rule>`        /products/1234 will be passed on to /products/index.jsp?product_id=1234 . I am unable to find where I an wrong

Comment: The rule is wrong. However the one from the question should forward to another URL for which you didn't post mapping.

Comment: I tried but didnt get any answer for this

Comment: Strange, it worked fine for me.